# Jmeter- CSRF value correlation issue - conversion from hex to string

Tags: jmeter, csrf, performance-testing, correlation

Correlated CSRF token value changes from one format to another, how to handle this in Jmeter.

Server sends a value                      `tjIAKJprJ\x2FxoK2GJL\x2BZMhgUm9Wat4j16dw\x2B7o4d9Lak\x3D`

It is used in further requests as      `tjIAKJprJ/xoK2GJL+ZMhgUm9Wat4j16dw+7o4d9Lak=`

following hex codes seem to have been changed :

```
\x2F   -->    /

\x3D   -->   =

\x2B    -->  +
```

Comment: It's URL-decoding that value.

Comment: Hi Joe, please let me know how to handle this in Jmeter tool.

Comment: ${__urldecode('${CSRF_referencename}')} , would this help please advise?

Comment: Guys, I got it resolved with this function ${__javaScript(decodeURIComponent('${csrftoken}'))}          
Thanks

Comment: you can add an answer and accept it

Comment: Issue has got fixed.